# VB.NET Invoke DLL method with ByRef Arguments

Tags: vb.net, dll, reference, arguments

Using VB.NET, is there a way to pass a reference argument when invoking a function in a dll.

Suppose I want to pass arg2 as a reference argument, how would I do that?

```
method.Invoke(obj, New [Object]() {arg1, arg2, arg3})
```

In other words I want to point arg2 to something else within the invoked function.

Answer (score 1):

If the target function defined as `ByRef` it'll work automagically otherwise AFAIK you can't.

Call it like :

```
method.invoke(obj, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

In your case you actually sending one parameter (an object array)

Comment: Yes, the target function argument is defined byref, but it does not work.

Comment: Yup, that's how I'm calling it.

Comment: OIC, what you're saying.  I don't believe there is an overload for that type of call.

Comment: yeah ParamArrays are quite useful stuff. So you can send parameters as much as you want to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the parameters in your object array will hold the values that were set inside the method call. One thing to be aware of is that if arg1, arg2 and arg3 are value types (like Int32) then the actual arg1 variable will not have been updated because its value was copied into the array not its reference.

To get around this, create the object array before the function call, then pull the values out of the array afterwards. Like this

```
Dim paramArray = New [Object]() {arg1, arg2, arg3}
method.Invoke(obj, paramArray)
arg1 = paramArray[0]
arg2 = paramArray[1]
arg3 = paramArray[2]
```

Comment: I like how you mixed VB and C# there.